# Google Sign in Authentication in not working in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am making a Login for Google Sign-in by using Firebase and I followed the docs of Firebase as well but I am not able to login after I choose a account.

The problem is onActivityResult the try is not running, it keeps on going to the catch part even if I change with if else there is no improvement.

Here is the code

Login.Java

```
 import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;
import com.tuyenmonkey.mkloader.MKLoader;



public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN =123 ;     // requestCode
    private SignInButton signInButton;
    private MKLoader loader;
    private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(currentUser!=null)
        {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this,GetData.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        
    }  // end od onStart

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.google_signin);
        loader = (MKLoader) findViewById(R.id.loader);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        createRequest();           // function to request google accounts to show
        signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                signIn();
            }
        });
    }  // end of onCreate



    private void createRequest() {

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        try  {
                  if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                      // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," Getting Google User's information " ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                      firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account.getIdToken());
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," Not in getting Google User's information " ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  }
            } catch (ApiException e) {

                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," Error in getting Google User's information "+e.getMessage() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(String idToken) {
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, GetData.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();

                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Getting Error while Authentication",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }



}  // end of AppCompatActivity
```

Comment: what is the exception that you are getting?

Comment: If you are interested in a clean Firebase authentication with Google, you can check this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check with what exception you are getting and I think it mostly should be because you might not have added the Google services properly or you might not have uploaded your SHA-1 number in the Firebase properly. Hope this helps with the minimum data of yours.